# How to overload an operator for integer, float and double data types simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, class, math, operator-overloading

I'm creating a 2D coordinate class (named “Point”) to help me learn C++. I want to be able to perform basic arithmetic operations (+, -, *, / ...) on Point class objects (e.g. Point_a + Point_b). However, I also want to be able to perform such operations between Points and other variable types (int/float/double).

This can be done using operator/function overloading. It can be seen from my code below (addition only) that I must, as far as I am aware, include two additional functions for each additional variable type, one for the “Point + int/float/double” form and one for the “int/float/double + Point” form.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    private:
        double x, y;

    public:
        Point(double x_in, double y_in){
            setX(x_in);
            setY(y_in);
        }    
        // Getters and Setters omitted for brevity

        // --- Start of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)

        friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point &p2);   //Point + Point
        friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, int val);           //Point + Int
        friend Point operator+(int val, const Point &p1);           //Int + Point
        friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, float val);         //Point + Float
        friend Point operator+(float val, const Point &p1);         //Float + Point     
        friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, double val);        //Point + Double
        friend Point operator+(double val, const Point &p1);        //Double + Point

        // --- End of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)
};

// --- Start of Addition Operator Overload Functions --- (Code Block B)

Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){
    return Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);
}

Point operator+(const Point &p1, int val){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(int val, const Point &p1){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(const Point &p1, float val){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(float val, const Point &p1){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(const Point &p1, double val){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(double val, const Point &p1){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

    // --- End of Addition Operator Overload Functions --- (Code Block B)
int main()
{
    Point point_a( 2.00, 20.00);
    Point point_b( 0.50,  5.00);
    Point point_c = point_a + point_b;
    cout << "X = " << point_c.getX() << " and Y = " << point_c.getY() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be a lot of repetition, particular between “Point + int/float/double” type functions. I was wondering if there is a way that this could be shorted a little. Say, rather than having individual versions for integer, float and double I could have one version which would handle all three. For example converting code blocks "A" and "B" into something like:

```
    ...

    // --- Start of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)

    friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point &p2);           //Point + Point
    friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, int||float||double val);    //Point + Int/Float/Double
    friend Point operator+(int||float||double val, const Point &p1);    //Int/Float/Double + Point

    // --- End of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)

    ...

...

// --- Start of Addition Operator Overload Functions --- (Code Block B)

Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point &p2){
    return Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);
}

Point operator+(const Point &p1, int||float||double val){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

Point operator+(int||float||double val, const Point &p1){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

// --- End of Addition Operator Overload Functions --- (Code Block B)

...
```

The above code section is intended to be representational of the desired result rather than actually functional (e.g. int OR float OR double).

In short, is there any way that I can make "`friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, int val);`" and its corresponding function (in code block B) accept integer, float and double values, or do I need to have an individual one for each variable type?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A template maybe?

Comment: As an aside:  Point(double x_in, double y_in){
            setX(x_in);
            setY(y_in);
        }    ' is superfluous. You can set x and y directly inside the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate solution than the template solution is to define constructors for the types you want to support, and have a single operator+ that works on Point types.

The compiler will implicitly call the proper constructor to convert the built-in type, before invoking operator+.

This simplifies the implementation, at the expense of wasted temp objects.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Point {
  private:
    double x, y;
  public:
    Point(int val) {
        this->x = val;
        this->y = val;
    }

    Point(double x, double y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point &p2) {
        return Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);   
    }
};

int main()
{
  Point p(1,2);
  Point q = p + 10;
  Point v = 10 + p;
}
```

There is a stylistic argument about explicitly white-listing supported types via the constructors, and blacklisting via static_asserts.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers mention templates but in actual fact, all numeric types will automatically be promoted to doubles.

Therefore, you only need to provide operators in terms of `Point` and `double`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
    private:
        double x, y;

    public:
        Point(double x_in, double y_in){
            setX(x_in);
            setY(y_in);
        }    
        // Getters and Setters omitted for brevity

        double getX() const { return x; }
        double getY() const { return y; }

        void setX(double v) { x = v; }
        void setY(double v) { y = v; }

        // unary ops
        Point& operator+=(Point const& other)
        {
            x += other.x;
            y += other.y;
            return *this;
        }

        Point& operator+=(double v)
        {
            x += v;
            y += v;
            return *this;
        }

        // --- Start of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)

        friend Point operator+(Point p1, const Point &p2)
        {
            p1 += p2;
            return p1;
        }

        friend Point operator+(Point p1, double val)
        {
            p1 += val;
            return p1;
        }

        friend Point operator+(double val, Point p1)
        {
            p1 += val;
            return p1;
        }
        // --- End of Addition Operator Overloads --- (Code Block A)
};


    // --- End of Addition Operator Overload Functions --- (Code Block B)
int main()
{
    Point point_a( 2.00, 20.00);
    Point point_b( 0.50,  5.00);
    Point point_c = point_a + point_b;
    point_c += 10;
    Point point_d = point_c + 10;
    Point point_e = point_d + 10.1;
    cout << "X = " << point_c.getX() << " and Y = " << point_c.getY() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Such can be more generalized by using templates and specializing the exceptional case, instead of providing an overloaded version for each and every matching type:

```
class Point
{
    public:
        // ...        
        template<typename T>
        friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, T p2);             
};
```

---

```
template<typename T>
Point operator+(const Point &p1, T val){
    static_assert(std::is_artithmetic<T>::value,"An arithmetic type is required");
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}

// Specialization for Point
template<> 
Point operator+(const Point &p1, const Point& val){
    return Point(p1.x + val, p1.y + val);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do this using templates:

```
// inside the class
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, int> = 0>
friend Point operator+(const Point &p1, T val) {
    // function definition
}

// Don't forget to define the function for T on the left hand side
```

This uses [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic), to make this function only accept types that are "arithmetic types", basically integers and floats.

Comment: Caveat: if `T` is a reference this will not work as expected.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't expect `T` to ever be a reference in calling this function, as I take `val` by value.

Comment: Why this approach, rather than define constructors that take int, float, and double, and then just have a single friend function that takes two points? Then the compiler will choose the appropriate conversion constructor.

Comment: @Alan That's a pretty good idea. Sometimes, you have some design requirement that prevents you from doing so, but that's definitely a good solution to the problem. You could post that as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Point's `operator+` implementations all converts its non-Point arguments to doubles before doing a `+` on elements.

The `float` and `int` overloads are nearly pointless.  Just write the two `double` overloads.

Built-in conversion from `int` and `float` will then occur in the `operator+` call.

---

If you really need int/float overloads and you know why and have tested that the double overload doesn't work, consider fixing the broken template conversion operator which is about the only way I can see this bbeing the case.

Failing that, cast to double explicitly.

**Failing that**, maybe write a template `+` that takes any `T` convertible to `double`, then converts and calls the above `+` for `double`.  Then add a paragraph of documentation why you had to do something this stupid and complex instead of just overloading `+` with `double`.  Then read that paragraph and change your mind and stick with `+` overloaded with `double`.